# Is using an ImageMap for a navigation menu considered good practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagemap

Should I use an ImageMap to create a navigation menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do, you need to address accessibility concerns.

[This article](http://jimthatcher.com/webcourse5.htm) has some information on how you might go about achieving that.